# Object Requires a specifier or qualifier in object c class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am building class to is a sub class of CCSprite:

The problem is i keep getting "Type name requires a specifier or qualifier".

I have the code commented where i get the errors. Im not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
int tileSize = 80;
Boolean moveable = true;
id moveUp,moveRight,moveDown,moveLeft;

@interface Player : CCSprite {

//On these lines. 
moveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0, 0 - tileSize)];
moveDown = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0,0+tileSize)];
moveRight = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0+tileSize,0)];
moveLeft = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(0-tileSize,0)];


}


-(void)move;



@end


@implementation Player{





@end
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you refrain from writing another line of Objective-C code until you become familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put code in your interface like that - it needs to be in a method or function.  The only things that should be in there are a list of properties.